# Word for someone who wants to find a single word to describe a relatively obscure concept, and posts such questions on internet boards?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a word for someone who wants to find a single word to describe a relatively obscure concept, and posts such questions on internet boards.  If I'm informed of such a word (or even a short phrase to the same effect), I'll be able to communicate more clearly, concisely, and precisely in the internet fora that I frequent.

Comment: This has a distinct feel of being off-topic to it… and yet I can't help but upvote!

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/2085).

Comment: ...... annoying

Comment: Please migrate this posting to ELU.meta.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the edit. It's actually a lot funnier now. :D

Comment: Meta! ...nicely done. ;)

Answer (score 6):

> Potential English Language & Usage user

Answer (score 5):

What about monologomaniac?

PS. I do like your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the term you are after is *Stack-barker*. Or possibly *Stack-breaker*.

Comment: ..... Stackler?